# JQuery assign HTML content to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get HTML code to jquery variable and it is working in following code:

```
var html_var = $(this).parent().html();
```

But when I want to modify "html_var" I cannot do it, I mean, the html code contains button tag and I need to change this button's value and id? I tried with "find" but I don't why it didn'y work.

```
var modified_var = html_var.find('.button').attr('id');
```

Comment: `.html()` gets the html, not the DOM elements, so you can't find the button by class etc.

Comment: Than how can I modify the content?

Comment: Either manipulate the DOM: `$(this).parent().find(".button").attr("id", someValue)` or use regex/replace to manipulate the html text. Depends on your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.html() returns the html as plain text, so you can either operate on the parent object:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent();
$parent.find.('.button').attr('id', newValue);
```

or you can operate on the text

```
var html_var = $(this).parent().html();
//modify the text
$(this).parent().html(html_var); //replace the parent html with the modified html
```

Comment: This method is working but after modifying $parent.find('button').attr('id', 'new_value'); and I tried to print $parent in alert but it displayed [Object obejct]

Comment: How can I use $print with modified version?

Comment: $parent is a jquery object. To display its inner html you can still try outputting `$parent.html()`

Answer (score 2):

```
var modified_var = $(html_var).find('.button').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var html_var = $(this).parent().html(); //Get HTML code
//Modify html_var
//...
$(this).parent().html(html_var); //Reapply modification
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, do not use the .html() in the html_var.

```
var html_var = $(this).parent();
```

Since it is a button tag you do not use the period/fullstop (.)  Instead do this:

```
var modified_var = html_var.find('button');
```

Notice there is no (.) in the find?

To change the id do this:

```
modified_var.attr("id","new_id_goes_here");
```

To change the value of the button do this:

```
modified_var.html("value of button here");
```

To find out what the id is you can do this:

```
var theid = modified_var.attr("id");
```

EDIT:

Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0huhx3v/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got an error "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Can you post the code you tried which received this error?

Comment: var html_var = $(this).parent().html();
var modified_var = html_var.find('button');
modified_var.attr('class');

Comment: Yes thanks it's working but I have to change button id and I have to use this variable. For example now the id is changed for $modified_var and with modified $modified_var I want to print but it returns me [Object object]